# jquery $("#id").load() not triggering document.ready() for second time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jqgrid

I am using jquery in asp.net MVC3 on Razor view engine. I have jquery tab control and on tab navigation i load myusercontrol.cshtml pages. On myusercontrol.cshtml page i have

```
 $(document).ready(function (){ loadjqgrid();});.
```

On click of each tab i do this

```
 $("#fragment-1").load("MyAction_in_controller");
```

this is called only for the first time when i click the tab, on second click control is not passed to the controller. Instead nothing happens.
Please advice.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: please post some html, so we can get better understanding of the situation

Answer (score 3):

`$(document).ready` only gets triggers on `DOMContentLoaded` event which can only happen once. Loading in new content cannot trigger that event.

Instead, abstract the code behind it into a function and call that function.

```
function domready () {
    // do stuff
}

$(document).ready(domready);

$("#fragment-1").load("MyAction_in_controller",domready);
```

However, there is more than likely a better way to handle it such as delegated events.

Comment: Each and every tab item handles seperate page/usercontrol deals with seperate model in MVC. hope above suggested wontwork.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @ComputerSurgeon Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. If the page doesn't reload entirely, the `DOMContentLoaded` event won't be triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to run `loadjqgrid` each time a tab is clicked after the load event? If so you can do:

`$("#fragment-1").load("MyAction_in_controller",loadjqgrid);`